# PHP - How to get list of items separated by \n inside array that requires PHP's comma to seperate the values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So I have code that grabs each line as seperate in a textarea.
For example:

1
2
3

would be 1,2,3.
Three different values.

I need to then put these values inside Shoppys array but with a comma seperating the values.
I've been stuck on it for so long now.

I even tried wrapping the foreach outside the array but it doesn't let me do that and it wouldn't work in theory anyway as it would send the array for all values.

My code:

```
            $acs = htmlspecialchars($_POST['acs']);

            // Do our magic foreach loop for each new line
            $array = explode("\n", $acs);
            $accounta = '';

            foreach($array as $line){
                if (empty($line)) { 
                    echo 'A line in the accounts field is empty. Please 
                    remove it and try again.'; 
                } else {                        
                    // Here we want to acc the account as an array inside the create-product Shoppy function
                    $accounta .= "$line\n";

                }
            }

            // Shoppy add product here
            $product = \Shoppy\Models\Product::create([
                "title"         => "$title",
                "price"         => $price,
                "unlisted"      => false,
                "type"          => "$servtype",
                "currency"      => "$currencyp",
                "confirmations" => 1,
                "stock_warning" => $stockwarning,
                "quantity"      => [
                    "min" => $minq,
                    "max" => $maxq
                ],
                "email"         => [
                    "enabled" => $emailr
                ],
                "accounts" => [
                    /*
                        'testa', 'rami', 'totas'
                        '1','2','3',
                    */
                    $accounta
                ]

            ]);
```

As you can see, the format I need is: `'testa', 'rami', 'totas'`

The $accounta will not read the comma even if I create it inside the foreach above at the top of my code as it's reading it as a string.

This is the new code i was told to use implode with:

[image]

ok so now it adds the product but does not seperate correctly by , as it's adding all inside 1 account:

[image]

Comment: Wait, wut? I think they mean `"accounts" => $array` so that you send an array containing the 3 items.

Comment: If they really want a comma-separated string of the three items, then you're using `explode()` to tear a string into an array and can use `implode()` to glue the pieces back together again.

Comment: This it's `"accounts" => implode(",", $array)`

Comment: "The $accounta will not read the comma even if I create it inside the foreach above" No you're not. $accounta .= "$line\n"; is not adding a comma , just the value and new line (\n).

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I know I changed back but I did try ,

Comment: Changed back from what?

Comment: @NigelRen can you give sample of the `$array` inside the implode as you can see the way I'm doing it above

Comment: @NigelRen check above. I edited the question with the implode trial and response. It's not working.

Comment: Screenshots or the _worst possible way_ to post code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out how to do it.
I had to do it differently as I couldn't make a foreach loop as it's already inside an array and wouldn't want to loop the whole array... just the items being inserted into the accounts array.

My final working code:

```
            $acs = htmlspecialchars($_POST['acs']);

            // Do our magic foreach loop for each new line
            $accountArray = explode("\n", $acs);
            $accountant = array();

            foreach($accountArray as $line) {
                if (empty($line)) { echo 'A line in the accounts field is empty. Please remove it and try again.'; } else {

                    // Here we want to acc the account as an array inside the create-product Shoppy function
                    //$accounts[] = "$line";
                    array_push($accountant, "$line");

                }
            }

            // Shoppy add product here
            $product = \Shoppy\Models\Product::create([
                "title"         => "$title",
                "price"         => $price,
                "unlisted"      => false,
                "type"          => "$servtype",
                "currency"      => "$currencyp",
                "confirmations" => 1,
                "stock_warning" => $stockwarning,
                "quantity"      => [
                    "min" => $minq,
                    "max" => $maxq
                ],
                "email"         => [
                    "enabled" => $emailr
                ],
                "accounts" => $accountant
            ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the

```
$array = explode("\n", $acs);
```

and you have the values:

```
Array (
    [0] => testa
    [1] => rami
    [2] => totas
)
```

You can just do

```
$comma_separated_values = implode(',', $array);
```

and `$comma_separated_values` would be a string that looks like this:

```
'testa', 'rami', 'totas'
```

In your case you should just put this in:

```
// Shoppy add product here
$product = \Shoppy\Models\Product::create([
        "title"         => "$title",
        "price"         => $price,
        "unlisted"      => false,
        "type"          => "$servtype",
        "currency"      => "$currencyp",
        "confirmations" => 1,
        "stock_warning" => $stockwarning,
        "quantity"      => [
        "min" => $minq,
        "max" => $maxq
    ],
    "email" => [
        "enabled" => $emailr
    ],
    "accounts" => [$comma_separated_values]
    ]);
```

Look carefully at your code:

```
$accounts = $array

and 

//This would contain an array with the same values as $array
$accounts = [$comma_separated_values]`
```

---

If you just do:

```
`$accounts = $comma_separated_values`
```

it would probably be an error because it seems it ***wants an array and this is just a string*** :-)

---

I don't know but my qualified guess is that this should work based on above!

```
// Shoppy add product here
$product = \Shoppy\Models\Product::create([
        "title"         => "$title",
        "price"         => $price,
        "unlisted"      => false,
        "type"          => "$servtype",
        "currency"      => "$currencyp",
        "confirmations" => 1,
        "stock_warning" => $stockwarning,
        "quantity"      => [
        "min" => $minq,
        "max" => $maxq
    ],
    "email" => [
        "enabled" => $emailr
    ],
    "accounts" => $array
    ]);
```

**On the sidenote:**
Please enter a more descriptive name for the `$array` (e.g. `$account_array`)

Comment: Should "accounts" be an array or a string? What is supposed to be? Have you tried with "accounts" => $comma_separated_values ?

Comment: What does "no luck mate" mean? What happens?

Comment: this is what it is showing when I try to use the `"accounts" => $comma_separated_values` : https://i.gyazo.com/dd0f2da128a5e1e61b69d22cb92608b5.png

Comment: I think you have to read up on what is really required. You tested with a string and an array. As I see it this does not seem to be a solvable issue without knowing what is actually required.